# dynamically adding new host in nagios

Tags: nagios

I having nagios server which monitoring xml files available in directory.

Each xml file has unique id, based on the id i create the host in the nagios server with the help of configuration file.

so every xml file has host and corresponding services.

number of xml files in the directory is not fixed, it will change during run time.

So how i can add new host(host config file) for newly added xml file with different id in the directory in runtime?

Is it possible to add new host from nagios webconsole ?

Thanks.

Comment: The web console is simply a readout of what nagios is doing and can't be configured (except for things like disabling notifications, etc). At least, that's with Nagios Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [external commands](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandlist.php) (e.g `RESTART_PROGRAM`) to reload the nagios configuration files each time a new XML file trigger a new host config file.

To automate, you could use a service which check new XML files and an event handler to use the `RESTART_PROGRAM` external command.

Comment: i want to add new config file automatically for new xml file with new id which is not already available in nagios host.